# Is it a reference to a function or what?

Tags: c++

What does the following declaration mean?

```
typedef int (&rifii) (int,int);
```

Is it a reference to a function? If yes, shouldn't it be initialized?

Comment: http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t287939-reference-to-a-function.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It defines the *type* "reference to a function taking two `int`s and returning an `int`". Variables of that type need be initialized, but you can't put an initializer into a typedef. It's not different to e.g. `int`:

```
int i;

typedef int& intref; // no initializer allowed
intref ri(i); // initializer required

int f(int, int);

typedef int (&rifii) (int,int); // no initializer allowed
rifii rf(f); // initializer required
```

Comment: What do you mean by `initializer required`?

Comment: @Nawaz: With "Initialier required" I mean that you have to give an initializer, that is, to initialize it at the definition. For example in `int a = 3;` the `= 3` part is the initializer. As is the `(5)` in `int b(5);`. In the case above, it means `intref ri;` would be an error because there's no initializer, but `intref ri(i);` is OK because there is an initializer (namely `(i)`).

Answer (score 2):

It's a `typedef`, so it can't be "initialized", it just introduces a new name for the type "reference to function returning an int and taking two ints as arguments".

Answer (score 1):

It is a reference to a function which takes two arguments and whose return type is an `int`

A typedef isn't initialized:

```
typedef int (&rifii) (int,int);
```

When you declare a reference of type `rifii` only then it must be initialized.

```
rifii r = foo;
```

Where '`foo`' is a function, `int foo(int, int);`

Answer (score 0):

It is a `typedef` to a *reference* to a function. And typedef cannot to be initialized. Think of `typedef int rank_t;` there is no initialization neither.

Answer (score -2):

`typedef` is like going into a dinner party and saying *hello, I am Ed* - no meat on that dish. The definition will give the flesh to those bones.

Comment: For those who cannot understand a metaphor. It is a declaration.

Comment: No, it isn't. A declaration would read `extern int (&rifii) (int,int);`. A typedef is something different. For a more apt metaphor, he's saying "Hi, I'm Slartibartfast. *But you can call me Slart.*"

Comment: Well, since my comment edit failed, I add to it (and add the at-attribution here) with this extra comment: Actually my better metaphor is still not a good one because it still suggests a single object. An even better metaphor would be a biologist saying: "We are going to talk about canis lupus familiaris, but let's just say dog."

Comment: Hindsight is a wonderful dish that should be served cold!. How many clinches in that one!